# MySQL query issues when deleting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple database as follows.  It maps employees to which department(s) they are a part of.  When an employee leaves, their records need to be deleted from both the `Employee` table and the `EmployeeDepartment` table.  Likewise, departments can change as well.  When a department changes, the record will need to be deleted from the `Department` and `EmployeeDepartment` tables.

I have a query that *mostly* works.  However, I did find some bugs in it when other records start getting deleted.  I was hoping someone could check it for me.

```
DELETE e, ed FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN EmployeeDepartment ed ON e.id = ed.id
WHERE ed.id = ?
```

The `?` being the ID of the record I want to delete.

**Edit**

To further explain, the delete won't work if the id isn't in both `Employee` and `Department`.  So if an employee has been created, but not yet assigned to a department, then the delete won't work.

Comment: You should look into foreign key constraints, particularly cascading delete.

Comment: I don't have the ability to make a more advance database right now...how would you suggest doing it using joins?

Comment: Do you have columns 'e' and 'ed' in the same Employee table?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
DELETE e, ed FROM Employee e 
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDepartment ed ON e.id = ed.id
WHERE e.id = ?
```

Note that you must match against `Employee`, since you say `EmployeeDepartment` isn't guaranteed to have records.

However, I see zero reason to do this as a single query.  It adds complexity for no real benefit.  Use two queries and wrap them in a transaction to make them atomic.  Start a transaction, delete from `Employee`, then delete from `EmployeeDepartment`, then commit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have columns 'e' and 'ed' in the same Employee table?
If not, try this:

```
DELETE e.*, ed.* FROM Employee e 
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDepartment ed ON e.id = ed.id
WHERE e.id = ?
```

If this doesn't help, then define **foreign key** constraints on the tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables.

Check this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html